# Java nested generic casting (? super Type)

Tags: java, generics, casting, bounded-wildcard

I tried to wrap my head around a problem I cannot seem to find an answer for.
Consider the following 2 examples:

```
{
    // this works.
    Consumer<CharSequence> c = F -> {};
    test(c);
}
static void test(Consumer<? super String> c) { /* content */}
```

and:

```
{
    // doesn't compile
    List<Consumer<CharSequence>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    test(list);
}
static void test(List<Consumer<? super String>> list) { /* content */ }
```

There might be a valid reason why the second example is not compiling/type-safe, but I cannot find/deduct this reason. So any help in clarifying this is appreciated.

Comment: you need `List<? extends Consumer<? super String>>` which is a parent for `List<Consumer<CharSequence>>`

Comment: @Andrew Tolbilko I had to think thrice about that one, but that would make sence. But what if you want this method to accept both `List<Object>` and `List<Consumer<CharSequence>>` (since I would only add to it)? for the first you would use `super` instead of `extends`, but that would break the second one. Or is it just not possible to let it accept both?

Comment: `List<? extends Object>` would work for it, they are too different types, so it's impossible to find a closer parent

Comment: I found a better alternative (altough it isn't a short one) : `static <T extends Consumer<? super String>> void test(List<? super T> list);`